# How to disappear the loading screen after sign in/register? (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When the user starts my app the first time, he can toggle between the registration form and the sign in form. After completing one of this forms, he should see the loading screen until the user is created or signed in. In my case, unfortunately, the loading screen doesn't disappear, although the user is created.
How can I fix this problem?

**the sign in form:**

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  SignIn({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool loading = false;

  // text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';

  static const color = const Color(0xFF2F80ED);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/canvas-1-ws.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 25.0,
                  left: 5.0,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 35.0,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Welcome(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/canvas-2-ws.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 50.0,
                          right: 50.0,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Form(
                            key: _formKey,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Login',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Black',
                                    fontSize: 35.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 30.0,
                                ),
                                TextFormField(
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    fillColor: Colors.black,
                                    hintText: 'Email',
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        width: 1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        width: 1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                                      ? 'Bitte gültige Email'
                                      : null,
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() => email = val);
                                  },
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20.0,
                                ),
                                TextFormField(
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      fillColor: Colors.black,
                                      hintText: 'Passwort',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          width: 1.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          width: 1.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    obscureText: true,
                                    validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                                        ? 'Bitte gültiges Passwort'
                                        : null,
                                    onChanged: (val) {
                                      setState(() => password = val);
                                    }),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 45.0,
                                ),
                                ButtonTheme(
                                  minWidth: 200,
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    elevation: 0,
                                    color: color,
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                      side: BorderSide(color: color),
                                    ),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: color,
                                            spreadRadius: 10.0,
                                            blurRadius: 20.0,
                                            offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Login',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Roboto Light',
                                            fontSize: 25.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                        setState(() => loading = true);
                                        dynamic result = await _auth
                                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                                email, password);
                                        if (result == null) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            error = 'Falsche Email/Password';
                                            loading = false;
                                          });
                                        }
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

**the registration form is almost similar...**

**the file, where the user can toggle between the forms:**

```
class Welcome extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  Welcome({this.toggleView});

  @override
  _WelcomeState createState() => _WelcomeState();
}

class _WelcomeState extends State<Welcome> {
  static const color = const Color(0xFF2F80ED);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/canvas-1-ws.png'),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Image.asset('assets/canvas-2-ws.png'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/Skiclublogo_transparent.png',
                  scale: 4,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 200,
                  height: 50,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      elevation: 0,
                      color: color,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        side: BorderSide(color: color),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: color,
                              spreadRadius: 10.0,
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              offset: Offset(0, 3),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Registrieren',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto Light', fontSize: 25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => Register(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                ),
                ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 200,
                  height: 50,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                      elevation: 0,
                      color: color,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        side: BorderSide(color: color),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: color,
                              spreadRadius: 10.0,
                              blurRadius: 20.0,
                              offset: Offset(0, 3),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Roboto Light', fontSize: 25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SignIn(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**the auth file, where the user is created or logged in:**

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on FirrebaseUser
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // sign in anonmously
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      // create a new document for the user with the uid
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
          user.displayName, user.email, user.photoUrl, user.uid);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign in email & password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // register with email & password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      // update user info
      UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
      userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
      await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
      await user.reload();
      user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

      // create a new document for the user with the uid
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
          user.displayName, user.email, user.photoUrl, user.uid);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // current user
  void inputData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
  }
}
```

**the wrapper file, where the app checks if the user is new:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);

    // return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Welcome();
    } else {
      return DrawerNav();
    }
  }
}
```

**the loading screen file:**

```
class Loading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: SpinKitWave(
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Thank you very much when you've read through all of this!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always call setState after the user is created.

This will work

```
                      onPressed: (){ if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                    setState(() => loading = true);
                                    dynamic result = await _auth
                                        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                            email, password);
                                    setState(() => loading = false);
                                    if (result == null) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        error = 'Falsche Email/Password';
                                      });
                                    }
                                  }},
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. When I press the sign in button, the loading screen appears and after the sign in screen appears again...

Comment: Of course, I only removed the loading screen after  _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword, as you asked.
Maybe what you want is to navigate to another page, so use 
Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NewPage(),
                          ),
                        );

Answer (score 0):

Ill explain you my friend

set a `boolean` variable named loading

```
loading = false;
```

if `loading` is `true` display *loading screen* else display your form *ui* using `ternary operator`

while creating *user* change the `state` of `loading` so that *loading screen* will appear

```
 setState(() { loading=true; });
```

after *user* is created change the `state` of `loading` again to `false`

```
 setState(() { loading=false; });
```

*This is the template in `build` `function`*

```
loading==false?yourui():loading()
```